# Use interface as generic type with new constraint

Tags: c#

In C#, I've define an Interface like following:

```
public interface IClassA
{
    IEnumerable<T> Search<T>()
        where T : new();
}
```

and

```
public interface IClassB
{
    ...
}
```

If I do

```
public DoSomething(IClassA a)
{
    // Error: IClassB must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor.
    var result = a.Search<IClassB>();
}
```

How can I fix this so that I can pass **IClassB** as generic type in **IClassA.Search**? or this is impossible?

Comment: I don't think it's possible since an interface can't be constructed.

Comment: The documentation specifically says the `new()` constraint doesn't work on abstracts (an `interface` is abstract): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-constraint

Comment: The reason for having `new()` as a type constraint is so that you can construct instances of the type. So how do you intend to construct an instance of `IClassB` when no such thing can exist? In the alternative, if you're not actually constructing `T`s inside `Search`, why have the `new()` constraint?

Comment: If you want to continue with new operator in the Search function , then pass a class which has been derived from IClassB.
   
public class B : IClassB
{
}
....
var result = a.Search<B>();

Answer (score 1):

You added constraint [new()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-constraint) to your method, which means, that a type argument in a generic method declaration must have a public parameterless constructor. Interface can't have constructors. Remove `where T: new()` constraint.